# Need to Hide / Show submenu using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list item menu with submenus that I need to show / hide on parent click. I have this working in other areas of my site but I am having issues selecting this element to make it work.

The click element is also a link which I need to prevent default or disable so that the sub-menu shows.

I need to be able to click on the parent link to hide/show the submenu

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="main-nav-list uppercase">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-16 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-4356">
<a href="//localhost:3000/about/" aria-current="page">About</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-16 current_page_item menu-item-4420"><a href="//localhost:3000/about/" aria-current="page">About</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4421"><a href="//localhost:3000/about/management/">Leadership</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var mobileSub = document.querySelectorAll("menu-item a");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < mobileSub.length; i++) {
  mobileSub[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: 1) you need to add a dot in your class selector: `var mobileSub = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item a");` -- otherwise it will search for `<menu-item>` elements, not `<... class="metnu-item">`; 2) your code doesn o seem to have click handling etc., you're asking to write that for you?

Comment: mouseenter was supposed to be "click". I see I did not add the dot. This could be the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript code is not affects on your question.
And answer will be something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item').forEach((it) => {
  it.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault();
     it.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by i.Nemiro did not work in my test so tweaked it a little bit.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item').forEach((it) => {
  const subMenu = it.querySelector('.sub-menu');
  it.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
     ev.preventDefault();
     subMenu.classList.toggle('hide');
  });
});
```

check working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nj2fvdt0/2/).

Answer (score 0):

So the help of Nemiro, alx, & Douglas P, I was able to make this work:

JS:

```
var mobileSub = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item a");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < mobileSub.length; i++) {
  mobileSub[i].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

This was used on a standard WordPress menu at mobile width.